# Google map with custom marker shape seems not to work

Tags: google-maps, marker

I try to reduce the clickable/mouse-hover area to the round area of ​​the marker with a custom circle shape, but this area is still too big.

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: { lat: 40.97, lng: -2.3 },
  label: "A",
  title: "My custom title",
  map: map,
  shape: {
    coords: [14, 14, 14],
    type: 'circle'
  }});
```

You can try with this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d7m6fgou/12/) and see that the hover starts long before you get to the marker and always seems to be rectangular in shape.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this behavior but it seems that it only happens on my machine with any browser. The problem no longer occurs on other systems.

Chrome 99.0.4844.51
Windows 10 Pro 21H2